# Remove Item Not Updating RecyclerView After Swipe Refresh

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have implemented swipe to delete an item as well as pull to refresh items in a `RecyclerView`. The deleting working as intended until I perform a pull to refresh. After pulling to refresh, when I perform a deletion the recycler view does not seem to respond to the `notifyItemRemoved`.

I have also tried `notifyDataSetChanged` with the same results.

Retrieving and updating data:

```
private fun callForEarthquakeData() {
    swipe_refresh.isRefreshing = true
    earthquakeApiEndpoint.getEarthquakes()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeBy(::errorOnGetEarthquakes, ::successOnGetEarthquakes)
}
```

Setting up `RecyclerView` after a successful call for data:

```
private fun successOnGetEarthquakes(it: EarthquakeFeed) {
    swipe_refresh.isRefreshing = false
    rvEarthQuakes.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    adapter = AdapterEarthquake(this, it.features.toMutableList())
    rvEarthQuakes.adapter = adapter
    val dragDirs = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
    val recyclerItemTouchHelper = RecyclerItemTouchHelper(dragDirs, adapter)
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(recyclerItemTouchHelper)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvEarthQuakes)
}
```

Listener on swipe refresh layout to retrieve data:

```
swipe_refresh.setOnRefreshListener { callForEarthquakeData() }
```

Full Adapter Code:

```
class AdapterEarthquake(private val context: Context, private val items: MutableList<Feature>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(), ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    private val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(context.getString(R.string.earthquake_date_format), Locale.US)

    override fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): Boolean {
        Collections.swap(items, fromPosition, toPosition)
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
        return true
    }

    override fun onItemDismiss(position: Int) {
        items.removeAt(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder =
            ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.quake_list_item, parent, false))

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val viewHolder = holder as ViewHolder
        val item = items[position]
        val formattedLocalDateTime = sdf.format(item.properties.time)
        val formattedCoordinates = item.geometry.coordinates.let { "[${it[0]}, ${it[1]}, ${it[2]}]" }
        viewHolder.title.text = item.properties.title
        viewHolder.date.text = formattedLocalDateTime
        viewHolder.coordinates.text = formattedCoordinates

        when {
            item.properties.magnitude >= 7 -> viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            item.properties.magnitude >= 5 -> viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.lightRed))
            else -> viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                context.startActivity(Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(items[adapterPosition].properties.detailsUrl)))
            }
        }

        val title = view.quake_title!!
        val coordinates = view.quake_coordinates!!
        val date = view.quake_date!!
    }
}
```

I expect the `RecyclerView` to update with the removed item after `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called (as it does before the swipe data refresh), but the result is the following.

[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code that provided I suppose. Can you please post swipe refresh code?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have included more complete samples from the code. If there is anything else that would help let me know.

Comment: Do you have any code where there is a checking like `if(swipe_refresh.isRefreshing)  doSomething()`?

Comment: No - that is just to provide a loading spinner while the web call happens and dispel it after the data is updated.

Comment: This could be a problem with the emulator I suppose. The screenshot above is from a Pixel 2 API level 28 emulator. I will try it on my Samsung Galaxy S8 physical device now and update.

Comment: Confirmed the same behavior occurs on my Samsung Galaxy S8 also running API level 28.

Comment: I found nothing wrong yet. Please post your full adapter and remove the code which is repeated.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have included the full adapter code in the original post, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please check the answer and let me know if that helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is where you set the new items when you pull and refresh the `RecyclerView` again. In the `successOnGetEarthquakes` method, you are initializing a new adapter each time you get the data from the server.

You might just change the list passed to the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter. I am just posing some pseudo code in Java. I hope that helps!

```
private fun successOnGetEarthquakes(it: EarthquakeFeed) {
    swipe_refresh.isRefreshing = false
    rvEarthQuakes.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    // Just feed the list, do not create a new adapter
    if(adapter != null) {
        adapter = AdapterEarthquake(this, it.features.toMutableList())
        rvEarthQuakes.adapter = adapter
    }
    else adapter.setItemsList(it.features.toMutableList())

    // Call the notifyDataSetChanged here
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    val dragDirs = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
    val recyclerItemTouchHelper = RecyclerItemTouchHelper(dragDirs, adapter)
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(recyclerItemTouchHelper)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvEarthQuakes)
}
```

Hence create a new function in your adapter which just changes the `items` list. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Great to know that helped!